# How to get rid of "on behalf of" in Outlook?

Tags: amazon-web-services, outlook, amazon-ses

I have a webapp sending emails via Amazon SES.

```
If my customers open my emails from outlook, they see "on behalf of" with amazon email.

I tried to configure FROM_MAIL in SES without success. 

I need one of the 2:

1.) Configure SES somehow, so the outlook will see that the email came from my address

2.) Explain to my customers how they can disable "on behalf of" in their outlook clients
```

Can someone help me with one of these?

Answer (score 1):

This means `Sender` and `From` MIME headers are different in your emails. Why that happens is a different question.